# Java binary search tree delete recursive return removed element

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

this is my code at the moment. I don't know how to return the removed element. Right now it's returning the new root of the tree. Can you guys please provide some pointers? Thanks.

```
public SomeDataType remove(String key) {
    Node removed = remove(root, key);
    if (removed != null){
        return removed.data;
    }
    return null;
}
// TO DO: RETURN REMOVED NODE
private Node remove(Node n, String key) {
    if (n == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (n.data.getKey().compareTo(key) < 0){
        n.right = remove(n.right, key);
    }
    else if (n.data.getKey().compareTo(key) > 0){
        n.left = remove(n.left, key);
    }
    else{
        if (n.right != null){
            SomeDataType successor = leftMost(n.right).data;
            n.data = successor;
            n.right = remove(n.right, successor.getKey()); 
        }
        else{
            n = n.left;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
private Node leftMost(Node n) {
    if (n.left == null){
        return n;
    }
    else{
        return leftMost(n.left);
    }
}
```

Comment: show how your are using the code. it could be a problem that you have two methods with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your wrapper method create a variable to hold key and then return it.

```
public SomeDataType remove(String key) {
    E data = key //E is a generic data type
    Node removed = remove(root, key);
    if (removed != null){
        return data;
    }
    return null;
```